# Ember: How to force run loop to cycle before property change

Tags: ember.js

I'm working with chart.js in ember and am encountering a bug where the graph breaks when I update the graph data without rerendering the component.

I am dynamically rendering this component with the `{{component totalsChartComponent}}` helper so if I could just set `totalsChartComponent` to undefined and let it cycle through the run loop before I update the components data it should clear out the component and allow it to render properly

I was trying to do this like this:

```
Ember.run.next(this, function () {
  this.set('totalsChartComponent', undefined);
})
Ember.run.next(this, function () {
  this.set('totalsChartComponent', "ember-chart");
})
```

but this does not appear to be running the second function a full run loop cycle after the first. Does this look like it should be working or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing my code to

```
Ember.run.schedule("actions", this, function () {
  this.set('totalsChartComponent', undefined);
});

Ember.run.next(this, function () {
  this.set('totalsChartComponent', "ember-chart");
});
```

Here is my understanding of why this works:

Ember.run.next schedules an event in the run loop cycle after the current one. I believe that my two Ember.run.next calls were getting evaluated during the same run loop, waiting for that loop to finish and then both throwing their action into the following loop. Basically the multiple calls to `next` were not creating multiple run loops.

Ember.run.schedule schedules something in the current loop or creates one. By doing this and then calling `Ember.run.next` I achieve the desired effect of creating one run loop for the first function and then creating another run loop for the second one.